# Using R, Retrieve files which filenames that contains certain strings

Tags: regex, r

I have thousand of files from a certain directory:

```
filenames <- list.files("D:/MessData_Source", pattern="*.DAT", full.names=TRUE)
.....
.....

     [9998] "D:/MessData_Source/908-A0F7__01310012567794F.DAT" 
     [9999] "D:/MessData_Source/908-A0F7__01310015662858F.DAT" 
    [10000] "D:/MessData_Source/908-A0F7__01310015662859F.DAT"

....
....
```

Out of those more than 1000 files, I need to extract out ONLY those files with filenames which contain certain strings.
**e.g.**

```
filename_extracted <- list()
for (i in 1:length(filenames))
{
  # search for those filenames that contain the strings with PartNo and MoNo and store in results
  filename_extracted[[i]] <- substr(filenames[i],31,43)
}
```

Above I am extracting the filenames string from number 31 to 43 and store it in filename_extracted which is something like this:

```
 [[9993]]
 [1] "1856955908850"

 [[9994]]
 [1] "1856955933372"

 [[9995]]
 [1] "1856955933372"

 [[9996]]
 [1] "1856955954613"

 [[9997]]
 [1] "1856955954613"

 [[9998]]
 [1] "1310012567794"

 [[9999]]
 [1] "1310015662858"

 [[10000]]
 [1] "1310015662859"
```

Next, I need to compare the filename_extracted to my required list, and copy those matched files to another directory.

```
required_list <- list()
df <-read.csv("PartNo_MoNo.csv")  # full set
for (i in 1:length(df))
{
  required_list[[i]] <- paste(df[i,1],df[i,2], sep="")
}
> required_list
[[1]]
[1] "1235235987252"

[[2]]
[1] "1897865985468"
```

If there are matches between required_list and filename_extracted, I want to copy the matched files to another directory, how do I do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated code, fully vectorized:

```
filename_extracted = substr(filenames, start=31, stop=43)
prefix             = substr(filesnames, start=20, stop=30)
required_list      = paste0(df[,1], df[,2])

common_suffix      = intersect(filename_extracted, required_list)
common_prefix      = prefix[filename_extracted %in% common]

storeDir = "D:/MessData_Source"
otherDir = "D:/OrderedData_Source"

if(length(common!=0))
{
    commonFile = paste0(common_prefix, common_suffix, ".DAT")

    sapply(commonFile, function(u){
        file.copy(file.path(storeDir,u), file.path(otherDir, u))
    })
}
```

Before executing this, make sure `otherDir` is created.

Comment: Hi Colonel Beauvel & Dieter Menne, thanks for both of your responses, I understand your code... but I need some modifications..., as the first 10 characters are not always "908-A0F7__". It could be "908-A0F7__01310015662859F.DAT" or "908-A062__01042105733247P.DAT" or "908-A050_A01042045683782P.DAT" or "108-0626_B09120015857047A.DAT" or "258-5141_B01963555909713F.DAT" or "108-0626_B09120015774259A.DAT". We can see that the filename is always contained 29 characters, including its .DAT extension.

Comment: Edited to this effect! Next time mention it in your question ;)

Comment: sorry... I still need to extract the last 5 characters also...and append to the commonFile...suffix = substr(filenames, start=44, stop=48)  # last 5 characters....commonFile = paste0(common_prefix, common_suffix, suffix)
  
  sapply(commonFile, function(u){
    file.copy(file.path(storeDir,u), file.path(otherDir, u))  above codes does not work, it copies everything over.

Comment: I put the wrong delimiters in prefix, now edited. Do you realize that in your code if you have the file "908-A062__01042105733247P.DAT" in filenames, you extract 1042105733247P (and not 01042105733247P)? Is this the working you want (it means required_list may contain 1042105733247P) ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create data
library(stringr)

lapply(1:10, function(x){
  write.csv(head(iris),file=paste0("908-A0F7__",x,".csv"))
  write.csv(head(iris),file=paste0("notused__",x,".csv"))
})
# Only get files with correct pattern
pattern = "908-A0F7__(\\d+).csv"
files = data.frame(name=dir(pattern=pattern,full.names=TRUE))
files$num = as.integer(str_match(filenames$name,pattern)[,2])
required = c(1,3,5) # You can also read this in from your csv

myFiles = files[files$num %in% required,]

dir.create("copied")
file.copy(as.character(myFiles$name),file.path("copied",str_sub(myFiles$name,3)))
```

Comment: Hi Colonel Beauvel & Dieter Menne, so we see that we need to get some kind of correct indexes for those "common" from intersect, such that it is able to extract out the correct first 11 characters and the last 5 characters (one alphabet + .DAT), and put them back into their filenames.